# how to find that a blocked user is using a different account on my system?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, fraud-prevention

I have a scenario where:
[image]

- User A is (fraudster).
- User B is not (fraudster). However, the system will not allow user B to do any action. Because B and A are using the same Phone Number(Shared attribute with Fraud User).(1 layer).
- User D is not (fraudster). But D is using the same Deviceid with B and B is sharing attribute with fraud User. Then block User D as well. In this case, there are 2 layers. D compare with B, B compares with A. In this sample example there are 3 users. if I have 100 users! the query will be very long which will have 99 layers.

*Note: I do not want to Update B and D to be a fraudster. they are just shared attributes with fraud users. So If I decided to change user A to be not a fraudster. No changes with the other users.

Comment: Whatever are you talking about?!?  Could you please clarify your question with a few specific examples?

Comment: @paulsm4 I do not have a code for this. Let me change the scenario a little bit. I have a table for users in my DB. each user has 4. (Email, Phone, IP, Device Id, and status). 
User A's Status is a fraudster. which means User A can not use the system. 
He/she diced to open a new account(User B). however, my system will check the sharing attributes between A and B It returns that B and A are using the same Phone. Means B becomes fraudster.

Comment: @paulsm4 can you read the question again? I have updated it. some people suggested using recursive CTE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest Question is pretty abstract, so need to make few assumptions as follows,

1. Assuming database server as MySQL
2. Considering this that data of fraudster accounts is already present in table.
3. The duplication of fields `MobileNo OR DeviceId OR EmailId OR IPAddress` decides fradster.

So to answer your question,

1. Create a `AfterUpdate` trigger on your `table`.
2. In that trigger `Fetch` and `Update` rows those having duplicate value for either `MobileNo` *OR* `DeviceId` *OR* `EmailId` *OR* `IPAddress`.

Fire Update query only if, `NEW.IsFraudsterStatus = 1`,

```
if (NEW.IsFraudsterStatus = 1) THEN
     UPDATE tableUser
     SET IsFraudsterStatus = 1
     WHERE 
          (tableUser.MobileNo = NEW.MobileNo
          OR
          tableUser.DeviceId = NEW.DeviceId
          OR
          tableUser.EmailId = NEW.EmailId
          OR
          tableUser.IPAddress = NEW.IPAddress)
         AND
          IsFraudsterStatus = 0; 
ELSE
     UPDATE tableUser
     SET IsFraudsterStatus = 0
     WHERE 
          (tableUser.MobileNo = NEW.MobileNo
          OR
          tableUser.DeviceId = NEW.DeviceId
          OR
          tableUser.EmailId = NEW.EmailId
          OR
          tableUser.IPAddress = NEW.IPAddress)
         AND
          IsFraudsterStatus = 1;
END IF;
```

In above query you may add as much as `conditions` you need, please note by `OR`ing them so that account is fraudster if any of the condition is true.

3. Once above query is fired it will repeatedly update all such accounts as **Fraudster**. And Please note the `AND`ed condition it will prevent endless recursive triggering.

And besides this I would recommend a `BeforeInsert` trigger, that will validate and restrict fraudster account getting created.

Comment: Well, I got what you mean. I was thinking about this. But it is not what I am looking for. This way will effect account B and D. let's say that I have decided to change A to be not Fraudster. In this case, B and D will be Fraudster and A is not.

Comment: So you're guessing that the OP wants to check for certain conditions when a new "user account" record is added.  If so, your suggestion of using a BeforeInsert trigger is excellent advice :)  Frankly, though, I still have no idea what the question is :(

Comment: @ABDULAZIZNOREDINQADMOR Then in that case you can have `ELSE` block and fire *Update* query that removes fraudster status for user.

Comment: @paulsm4. Sorry, That's what I can do for now. I will try to provide a query for this.

Comment: @AniketBhansali How if A and B are fraudsters. if I remove fraudster status from user A. then User B will stay fraudster?

Comment: @ABDULAZIZNOREDINQADMOR Update my answer, please go through it for your query.

Comment: @AniketBhansali Your solution is working very well. But I do not want to update them. I just want to compare them. I think you miss understand. I have updated the question as well. Can you check it?. maybe, you will get me now. by the way bro thanks for helping